# Installing SSL certificate in Magento?

Tags: magento, web, ssl-certificate

I must install a SSL certificate for my Magento store and I have a question:
Is it better to install the SSL certificate in a subdirectory or in the main domain? (Ex: store.domain.com or domain.com)

My doubt is whether installing on the primary domain (domain.com) could harm the SEO ranking in Google, since the site will now respond with https?

Or does Magento handle this and loads the https pages only when necessary, like in the cart pages?

Answer (score 0):

Magento *can* use https only for certain pages (they're checkout, customer account and admin panel), but it depends on configuration. Please, see the Web→Secure→Base URL config option. You're probably want to set base URL as http://www.foo.com/ and base secure URL as https://www.foo.com/